# Joining with named scopes in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, scope, acts-as-tree

I originally asked this question about acts_as_tree but it seems to be more general so I'm rephrasing it a bit here.
I have a model "category" using acts_as_tree. I often find myself needing to join it with other models for various queries, but I don't know how to use the provided scopes such as children, ancestors, siblings, descendants to create the conditions that I need.

Concrete example:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
  has_many :photo
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :category
end

cat = Category.first
```

How can I query for all the photos of children of cat or all the photos of its siblings?
Seems like I need something like:

```
Photo.joins(cat.children)
Photo.joins(cat.siblings)
```

which I know is not a valid code.

Answer (score 0):

Since act_as_tree doesn't really use scopes but methods that return results, you can do it like:

```
class Photo
  belongs_to :category

  scope :from_category, -> (category) {
      joins(:category).where(category: category)
  }
end

cat = Category.first

Photo.from_category(cat.children)
Photo.from_category(cat.siblings)
```

And that should work.